# use a counter to access named list elements as ggtitle within mapply call

Tags: r, mapply

I'm generating and plotting multiple ggplots based on data from two lists, therefore I'm using `mapply`. One of the lists has named elements, which I would like to use as `ggtitle`. But it only takes the first element for all the plots

```
> names(sample_subset_list)
[1] "water after day 43 dna min reads per OTU 5"
[2] "biofilm after day 43 dna min reads per OTU 5"
[3] "water after day 43 cdna min reads per OTU 5"
[4] "biofilm after day 43 cdna min reads per OTU 5"
[5] "water after day 44 dna min reads per OTU 5"
[6] "biofilm after day 44 dna min reads per OTU 5"
[7] "water after day 44 cdna min reads per OTU 5"
[8] "biofilm after day 44 cdna min reads per OTU 5"
```

and this is the plotting function:

```
ordination_plots <- list()
counter <- 0
ordination_plots <- mapply(function(x,y,counter) {
                        counter <- counter + 1 
                        plot_ordination(x, y, type = "sample") + 
                            ggtitle(names(sample_subset_list)[counter]) +
}, x = sample_subset_list, y = ordination_nmds, counter = 0, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

this will give me plots where the title is always the first element of

`names(sample_subset_list)`.

The same happens calling `ggtitle(names(sample_subset_list)[]) +`

If I use `counter <<-` (suggested here: [Using a counter inside an apply structured loop in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029508/using-a-counter-inside-an-apply-structured-loop-in-r)) or call ggtitle like

`ggtitle(names(sample_subset_list)) +`

or

`ggtitle(names(sample_subset_list)[[]]) +`

I get no title at all.

I started without a counter, which also gave me the same title for all plots. Could someone explain to me how I can iterate over the names of the list elements to use them for the ggplots?

Comment: you passed `counter` as a parameter and are only modifying it locally. To modify it in the parent scope you need to use `<<-`. I'd remove it from the function def and mapply parameter list, too.

Comment: @hrbrmstr that worked, thanks! But I have to admit that I don't really understand, why it worked. Do you want to add this as answer and make it a little bit clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's reduce the complexity of the example:

```
counter <- 0

invisible(mapply(function(letter, counter) {

  counter <- counter + 1
  cat("Letter: ", letter, "; Counter: ", counter, "\n", sep="")

}, letters[1:10], counter))
```

NOTE: I only used `invisible()` to stop printing the result of `mapply()`.

`letters[1:10]` is a 10-element vector of lower-case letter (built in data).

You define `counter` outside of `mapply()`. Unlike `for` or `while`, functions in `mapply()` do not — by default — create or modify variables in the parent scope (outside of `mapply()`, so the result is this:

```
Letter: a; Counter: 1
Letter: b; Counter: 1
Letter: c; Counter: 1
Letter: d; Counter: 1
Letter: e; Counter: 1
Letter: f; Counter: 1
Letter: g; Counter: 1
Letter: h; Counter: 1
Letter: i; Counter: 1
Letter: j; Counter: 1
```

It's fine to pass in a second parameter with info to the function argument of `mapply()` but if the intent is to have a side-effect of incrementing something outside the scope of the function in `mapply()` then you really shouldn't pass it to in as parameter and just modify it using the `<<-` operator, which — according to the help page:

*"The operators `<<-` and `->>` are normally only used in functions, and cause a search to be made through parent environments for an existing definition of the variable being assigned. If such a variable is found (and its binding is not locked) then its value is redefined, otherwise assignment takes place in the global environment."*

So, we can just do this:

```
# TO MY FUTURE SELF AND TEAM MEMBERS
# `counter` is modified as a side-effect of operations in the `mapply()`
# that follows the object declaration
counter <- 0

invisible(mapply(function(letter) {

  counter <<- counter + 1
  cat("Letter: ", letter, "; Counter: ", counter, "\n", sep="")

}, letters[1:10]))
```

to get this:

```
Letter: a; Counter: 1
Letter: b; Counter: 2
Letter: c; Counter: 3
Letter: d; Counter: 4
Letter: e; Counter: 5
Letter: f; Counter: 6
Letter: g; Counter: 7
Letter: h; Counter: 8
Letter: i; Counter: 9
Letter: j; Counter: 10
```

The comment was not meant for snark. You are using a side-effect that may be non-obvious to your future self or folks you share the code with so noting it will help you re-figure out and them figure out what's happening.

Comment: alright, so I mixed defining a parameter inside the function called `counter` with updating a counter which was not part of the function. Thank you very much for the detailed explanation.